# Tabsequence un a DSPF subfile vertically, with multicolumn subfile

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

Is there a DSPF keyword, that defines that in a multi column subfile the cursor jumps to the first field in the occurrence on the same colomn, on the next line, when arriving from the last field in the column, in stead of the default behaviour, where the next entry on the same line gets the corsur position?

If I have

```
     C1F1a C1F2a  C2F1a C2F2a
     C1F1b C1F2b  C2F1b C2F2b
     C1F1c C1F2c  C2F1c C2F2c
```

C=Column, F=field

Tabbing on C1F2a should bring me on C1F1b.
Tabbing on C1F2c should bring me on C2F1a.

Answer (score 1):

The SFLCSRPRG (Subfile Cursor Progression) keyword looks like it will do what you want.

Comment: Functions in Client-Access, with Reflection it won't

Comment: Call Reflection support and let them know.